# Azure ActiveDirectory Graph API client Update user error: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Tags: .net, azure

I'm working with the Graph API in .Net.  I'm currently using version 2013-11-08 (2 behind newest).  One month ago everything was working properly, and then something changed (not in code) that caused updating users to break.  We can still create users successfully, we just can't update users passwords specifically.  The

```
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation..
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.ConnectionWrapper.InvokeNetworkOperation[T](Func`1 action)
```

I've double checked the Application Permissions within azure, and they are setup correctly (in fact, to test I've just given the application all permissions).  I'm at a loss with what to try next.

I'm currently looking into upgrade the application to use the newest version of graph api (1.6).

Does anyone have any ideas why I can no longer update users?  This ability stopped working sometime in the past month, but what's weird is how we can still create new users using the same client/api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/715a9082-56bd-4eb7-8e60-8420b8f67659/getting-authorizationrequestdenied-error-message-when-try-to-change-a-password-to-the-user-in#715a9082-56bd-4eb7-8e60-8420b8f67659),recent Microsoft Update on Security permissions might cause this .right now the fix can be applied only with the help of Powershell.

Here is the full details on the update http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2015/10/06/new-graph-api-consent-permissions.aspx

**Update:**

I have faced similar situation , below code made the application work again.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------
# This will prompt you for your tenant's credential
# You should be able to use your your Azure AD administrative user name
# (in the admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com format) -- **"I have given user who is in global admin role"**
#-----------------------------------------------------------
Connect-MsolService

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# Replace the Application Name with the name of your 
# Application Service Principal
#-----------------------------------------------------------
$displayName = "Application Name"
$objectId = (Get-MsolServicePrincipal -SearchString $displayName).ObjectId

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# This will add your Application Service Prinicpal to 
# the Company Administrator role
#-----------------------------------------------------------
$roleName = "Company Administrator"              
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName $roleName -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal - RoleMemberObjectId $objectId
```